# How to use multiple scripts on different sheets within a google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, scripting

I have a google sheet that has 10+ sheets in it. Each sheet has a different color theme that I do not want to be changed by my many editors.

I have developed a script to set the background colors. This is great for one sheet. But I would like to have an almost identical script for each sheet with a different color in each sheet. How can I achieve this?

I also realized that this script allows other users of the doc to be able to change cell colors. How can I prevent this from changing the formatting and only the text? (I tried to add my script but kept getting an error on it)

I got this script from the web. I'm using it 5 times in my full script.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:AN1"); 
range.setBackground("grey");
```

Comment: most simple is to repeate the script 10+ times

Comment: `I also realized that this script allows other users of the doc to be able to change cell colors. How can I prevent this from changing the formatting and only the text?` For this question you should share your script here, I assume.

Comment: _I also realized that this script allows other users of the doc to be able to change cell colors_ I'm pretty sure that you'll find that they can do more than change cell colors - they can probably change anything, anywhere, anytime. How have you shared your spreadsheet? How do your other users access your spreadsheet - what permissions do they have "Can Edit"?